# What is difference between naming Class name as MyClass and namespace\Myclass in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

I am new to PHP. I am just trying to understand PHP namespace and stuck at following point of changing the class name, I am referring this article titled [How to use PHP namespace](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-php-namespaces-part-3-keywords-and-autoloading/). And was referring following code on that page.

```
<?php
namespace App\Lib1;

class MyClass {
    public function WhoAmI() {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}

$c = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\MyClass';
$m = new $c;
echo $m->WhoAmI(); // outputs: App\Lib1\MyClass::WhoAmI
?>
```

In the above code, I guess, they have created Object like,

```
$c = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\MyClass';
$m = new $c;
```

I guess object can be created simple in above case as,

```
$m = new MyClass();
```

And on the same page, in other code the object has been created using code,

```
$m = new namespace\MyClass;
```

Now, if I compare all three above, I am finding two method of creating class name 1. `$m = new MyClass();` and 2. `$m = namespace\MyClass;`. I am wondering what is the difference and purpose of using `$m = namespace\MyClass;`? Very thank in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest advantage of using namespaces in PHP is for when you have multiple classes with the same name. Without namespacing, a developer would need to worry that by creating a class MyClass, there are thousands of other third-party libraries that could also have a MyClass.

Let's say you wanted to create a class called DateTime. If you just wrote the function without a namespace, it would conflict with PHP's DateTime class. By declaring a namespace, you segragate your code.

```
<?php

$myObject = DateTime(); // This statement creates an object using PHP's implementation of DateTime 

namespace Foo\DateTime;
use Foo\DateTime as DateTime;

$myObject = DateTime(); // This statement will use the custom class from the Foo\DateTime namespace

$myObject = PHP\DateTime(); // This statement will use PHP's class even though you're using the Foo\DateTime namespace

?>
```

The second advantage is for code conciseness. If you use the Foo\DateTime namespace shown above, you don't have to use the fully qualified name when you create custom objects from your class. This is useful when you have to create a large number of instances of your custom class.

When you use the namespace like so, you can write it as an alias instead of a fully qualified name:

```
use Foo\DateTime as DateTime;
$myObject = new DateTime();
```

Without using namespaces, you would need to create the object like so, if you wanted to use your DateTime class instead of PHP's DateTime class:

```
$myObject = Foo\DateTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are no any essential differences between:

`$m = new MyClass();` and `$m = new namespace\MyClass;`

It can help you to explicitly indicate which one of two classes with the same name you use:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

class MyClass {
    public function WhoAmI() {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}
?>

<?php
namespace Bar;

class MyClass {
    public function WhoAmI() {
        return __METHOD__;
    }
}
?>

<?php
namespace Bar;
use Foo;

$obj1 = new MyClass;
var_dump($obj1->WhoAmI()); //Bar\MyClass::WhoAmI

$obj2 = new namespace\MyClass;
var_dump($obj2->WhoAmI()); //Bar\MyClass::WhoAmI

$obj3 = new Foo\MyClass;
var_dump($obj3->WhoAmI()); //Foo\MyClass::WhoAmI
```

I think it is better to use [aliasing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) in this case.

Comment: Yes that's true, both are giving the same output. Thanks for the link, I am referring that link and trying to understand whole system, will post you a comment after. Thanks